# How to test my plugin architecture feature?

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, .net-assembly, plugin-architecture

I am implementing a simple plugin architecture in an application. Basically, there will be a simple string defining assembly names and fully qualified types of the plugins' respective main classes, and the host application is supposed to load the main class and call the `Initialize` method of the plugin class.

How can I make an NUnit style integration test for this? Can I create a stub MyPlugin type and save it as assembly (dll file) during the test's runtime (is this doable using certain library?)?  Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: why not use a simple pre-made assembly specifically for testing?

Comment: @mtijn That can work, but not sure what verification/assertion I can make to verify that the class was indeed loaded